# MessageDigest in Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, security

I am trying to translate java code to c#. I'm kind of stuck on this exercise below:

```
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      md.reset();
      md.update(pass.getBytes());
      byte[] enc = md.digest();
      StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < enc.length; i++) {
        String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & enc[i]);
        hex.append((h.length() == 2) ? h : ("0" + h));
      }
```

This is what I have tried but I am not getting the desired result which would be the following string: "e81e26d88d62aba9ab55b632f25f117d"

My Code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

string user_password = "HELLOWORLD";
byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user_password);
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1Managed.Create();
byte[] cryptPassword = sha1.ComputeHash(hashBytes);
user_password = Encoding.Default.GetString(cryptPassword);

StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < cryptPassword.Length; i++)
{

    // Store integer 182
    int intValue = cryptPassword[i];
    // Convert integer 182 as a hex in a string variable
    string hexValue = intValue.ToString("X");
    // Convert the hex string back to the number
    int intAgain = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    hex.Append((intAgain.ToString().Length == 2) ? intAgain : ("0" + intAgain.ToString()));
}

Console.WriteLine("pass: " + hex.ToString());
```

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: For starters, your expected result is the `MD5` hash, but your code is getting the `SHA1` hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is you are using `SHA1` function instead of `MD5`. Also Im not sure why you are looping over the password length. Every `MD5` hash will be the same length regardless of input size.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

string user_password = "HELLOWORLD";
byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user_password);
var md5 = MD5.Create();
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(hashBytes);

StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in hash)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
Console.WriteLine("pass: " + hex);
return ;
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Works!! G